# Some questions about set closure / Kuratowski closure.

Tags: general-topology

Here is the page that is confusing me: [Page 25 of General Topology (Willard)](http://books.google.ca/books?id=-o8xJQ7Ag2cC&lpg=PA25&ots=TRjbBfYzIu&dq=%22we%20will%20show%20k-c%20holds%22&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q=%22we%20will%20show%20k-c%20holds%22&f=false)

> **Definition 3.5** If $X$ is a topological space, and $E\subset X$, then the *closure* of $E$ in $X$ is the set 
>   $$\overline{E} = \mathrm{Cl}(E) = \bigcap \{K\subset X\mid K\text{ is closed and }E\subset K\}.$$
>
> [...]
>
> **Lemma 3.6** If $A\subset B$, then $\overline{A}\subset \overline{B}$.
>
> [...]
>
> **Theorem 3.7** The operation $A\mapsto \overline{A}$ in a topological space has the following properties:
>
> K-a) $E\subset \overline{E}$
>
> K-b) $\overline{(\overline{E})}=\overline{E}$
>
> K-c) $\overline{A\cup B} =\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$
>
> K-d) $\overline{\varnothing} = \varnothing$
>
> K-e) $E$ is closed in $X$ iff $\overline{E}=E$.
>
> Moreover, given a set $X$ and a mapping $A\mapsto \overline{A}$ of $\mathscr{P}(X)$ into $\mathscr{P}(X)$ satisfying K-a through K-d, if we define closed sets using K-e, the result is a topology on $X$ whose closure operator is just the operation $A\mapsto\overline{A}$ we began with.

Everything was fine until this page, and suddenly I'm utterly confused. **Definition 3.5** *defines* what a closure is, and **lemma 3.6** follows directly from this definition and is, it seems to me, almost self-evident... and then **Theorem 3.7** happens and I've no idea what's going on.

In the second-to-last paragraph, Willard implies that, in the collection **F** of all sets $\bar{A}=A$, $A \subset B \implies \bar{A} \subset \bar{B}$ does *not* directly follow from lemma **3.6**.

> We proceed now to the second part of the theorem. Let $X$ be any set and $A\to \overline{A}$ a mapping of $\mathscr{P}(X)$ into $\mathscr{P}(X)$ satisfying K-a through K-d. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the collection of all sets $A$ such that $A=\overline{A}$. The assertion is that $\mathscr{F}$ satisfies F-a through F_c of Theorem 3.4.
>
> First note that if $A\subset B$, then by K-c, $\overline{B}=\overline{A}\cup\overline{B-A}$, so that $\overline{A}\subset \overline{B}$ (why couldn't we just refer to Lemma 3.5?)

Wouldn't it follow even more clearly so? Isn't this valid: $ \bar{A} (= A) \subset \bar{B} (= B) \implies Lemma \; 3.6$

In fact, I'm having trouble understanding the significance of this Kuratowski closure operation altogether... don't K-a to K-e all follow from **Definition 3.5*?

I think I might need a more extensive article on this topic, because I don't fully understand the significance of the material on this page.

Comment: Please be aware that google book links are highly unstable. What you are allowed to see often depends on which country you are viewing from. As such, it would be best if the post is self-contained and includes the relevant definitions and lemmas.

Comment: About the tags: Not everything about sets is [set-theory]; questions *about* online resources fit into [online-resources], and not questions directing the reader to one; and reference request is a request for a reference, not asking about a specific source.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ok, thank. Wow you're fast with the LaTex.

Comment: @DavidMitra so I have to pay even closer attention to initial conditions and definitions than I'm previously used to. Missing that small detail completely threw me off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two parts to Theorem 3.7.

The first part says: if you *already* have a topological space $X$, and you define $\overline{A}$ as per Definition 3.5, then the operation $A\mapsto \overline{A}$ will satisfy condition K-a through K-e.

The second part of Theorem 3.7 says: suppose you have a set (**not** a topological space, just a set), together with a function from $\mathscr{P}(X)$ to $\mathscr{P}(X)$, denoted by $A\mapsto\overline{A}$ which just happens to satisfy conditions K-a through K-d. **Then** you can use this function to *define* a topology on $X$ by saying "$A$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $A=\overline{A}$."

Now, if you do that, you started with a function $A\mapsto\overline{A}$; now you have a topological space. Since you now have a topological space, you can use Definition 3.5 to define a closure operator on this topological space, by
$$\mathrm{Cl}(A) = \bigcap \{ K\subset X\mid K\text{ is closed and }A\subset K\}.$$
If you do this, what is the relationship between $\overline{A}$ and $\mathrm{Cl}(A)$? The answer, given in the last paragraph, is that if you do this two-step process, then the function $\mathrm{Cl}(A)$ will just be exactly $\overline{A}$. That is, the function you get by starting with your original map, then constructing the topology, and then using the topology to give you a closure operator is exactly the function you started with.

The reason you cannot invoke Lemma 3.6 in that paragraph is that the paragraph is taking place in the context of the *second part* of the theorem. That is, you do **not** have a topology and you do not have the closure operator defined by the topology; you just have *some* function from $\mathscr{P}(X)$ to $\mathscr{P}(X)$ which *happens* to satisfy conditions K-a through K-d; Lemma 3.6 is about the closure operator you define *once* you have a topology, but since you don't have a topology here yet, you can't use it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: I should refresh pages more often. Deleting my comments..

Comment: @DavidMitra just after I posted my reply to yours! haha, now this is like one of those Benny Hill chase scenes.