# Other equivalent definitions of topologies

Tags: general-topology

In my book, it defines topological space $\left(X,\mathcal{T}\right)$ satisfying the following axioms:

1. $X$ and $\emptyset$ belong to $\mathcal{T}$
2. The union of any number of sets in $\mathcal{T}$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}$
3. the intersection of any two sets in $\mathcal{T}$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}$

But there is another definitions of topologies which I don't know why it is equivalent.

1. Let $X$ be a non empty set and let there be assigned to each point $p\in X$ a class $\mathcal{A}_p$ of subsets of $X$ satisfying the Neighborhood Axiom. Then there exists one and only one topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ such that $\mathcal{A}_p$ is the $\mathcal{T}$-neighborhood system of point $p\in X$.
2. Let $X$ be a non empty set and let $k$ be an operation which assigns each subset $A$ of $X$ to the subset $A^k$ of $X$, satisfying the Kuratowski Closure Axioms. Then there exists one and only one topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ such that $A^k$ of $X$ is the $\mathcal{T}$-closure of subset $A$ of $X$.
3. Let $X$ be a non empty set and let $i$ be an operation which assigns each subset $A$ of $X$ to the subset $i(A)$ of $X$, satisfying

   (i) $i(X)=X$, (ii) $i(A)\subset A$, (iii) $i(A\cup B)=i(A)\cup i(B)$, (iv) $i(i(A))=i(A)$

   Then there exists one and only one topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ such that $i(A)$ of $X$ is the $\mathcal{T}$-interior of subset $A$ of $X$.

Comment: Proving the equivalence of these definitions is an exercise everyone is asked to do in topology. Solve it and then write it without words. You topology professor will be very happy.

Comment: @RGB: I am a G.11 student, haven't study in university. So maybe I am asking a silly question, but no professor can give me advice.

Comment: Another equivalent one is described at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/117756/uniqueness-and-existence-of-topology-for-a-given-convergence-class-of-nets

Comment: [R. Engelking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryszard_Engelking) in his book *General Topology*, in Section 1.2, gives several methods of generating topology (neighborhood system, closure operator) and he *includes* proofs that they indeed give a topology. Do you, by any chance, have access to this book?

Comment: The book "Introduction to Topology" by Mendelson does something similar, and I think it is a nice read. @MartinSleziak

Comment: @UnemChan There is an answer containing several resources containing details on various ways of generating topology. Maybe other users will add more. You could have a look and if something unclear to you, you could ask more specific question. I think it would be good: (a) to concentrate only on one way of generating topology in one question, (b) to say what exactly is unclear to you or for which part you were not able to find a proof.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several resources containing proofs that various methods of generating topology (such as [Kuratowski closure operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms), neighborhood systems) indeed give a topology have been already mentioned in comments. I am posting a CW answer, where we can collect such references. Feel free to edit this post if you have any relevant addition.

**Books**

- [R. Engelking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryszard_Engelking) in his
  book *[General Topology](http://books.google.com/books?id=K3spAQAAMAAJ)*, in Section 1.2, gives several methods of
  generating topology (neighborhood system, closure operator) and he
  *includes* proofs that they indeed give a topology.
- Kelley's *[General Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_important_publications_in_mathematics#General_Topology)* shows when net convergence determines a topology. Kuratowski closure operator is discussed in Chapter 1 (Theorem 8).
- In S. Willard's [General topology](http://books.google.com/books?id=-o8xJQ7Ag2cC) you can find the result about closure operator in Theorem 3.7 (it is also mentioned in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113004/some-questions-about-set-closure-kuratowski-closure)) and neighborhood systems are mentioned in Theorem 4.2.
- In Mendelson's [Introduction to Topology](http://books.google.com/books?id=vQPwuxcVABYC) you can find in Section III.3 the concept of neighborhood space and in Section III.4 the concept of closure space. Again, they are shown to generate a topology. (This book was mentioned in Peter Tamaroff's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444702/other-equivalent-definitions-of-topologies/444780#comment954290_444702).)

**Online**

- [Section 3](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/TopSection3.pdf) of Pete L. Clarks notes on general topology notes available from his website.

**Blog posts**

- On the The Unapologetic Mathematician's blog you can find definition of topology using [bases](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/11/22/bases-and-subbases/), [neighborhoods](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/11/15/neighborhoods/) and [closure](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/11/13/interiors-and-closures/).

**Searches**

- A lot of results returned when you search for [closure operator topology](http://www.google.com/search?q=closure+operator+topology) seem to be relevant for your question. You might try the same query in [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?q=closure+operator+topology)

Comment: Could I bother you in chat?

Comment: (Also, this is a very nice solution to an otherwise really broad question.)